# How to sort and merge elements of a column in a dataset

Tags: r, merge, datatable, subset, sentiment-analysis

I need to conduct a sentiment analysis on the messages of a data table containing two columns: the first one is the list of the "user", and the second one is the list of the "comment". Since to each user may be associated different messages, I need to subset my data table in order to obtain a new data table containing the unique users id and the combination of all the messages referred to each single user in the same cell, using the data.table library.

what is the code to use?

thank you.

Comment: your question is not clear. For example, what do you mean by "combination"? try to provide an example including your source table and desired output

Comment: Please show your part of your data as an example, so people have a better understanding of what you are tying to do

Comment: Please add data using `dput` or something that we can copy and use. Also show expected output for the data shared. Read about [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [how to give a reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269).

Answer (score 0):

Based on this sample data:

```
DT <- structure(list(User.ID = c(111, 222, 333, 444, 555, 111, 111, 
222, 222), Comment = c("Comment 111", "Comment 222", "Comment 333", 
"Comment 444", "Comment 555", "Second Comment 111", "Third Comment 111", 
"Second Comment 222", "Third Comment 222")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-9L))
```

Which looks like this:

```
   User.ID            Comment
1:     111        Comment 111
2:     222        Comment 222
3:     333        Comment 333
4:     444        Comment 444
5:     555        Comment 555
6:     111 Second Comment 111
7:     111  Third Comment 111
8:     222 Second Comment 222
9:     222  Third Comment 222
```

We can use `data.table`:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(DT)
DT[ , (id = paste(Comment, collapse=",")), by = User.ID][, .("User ID" = User.ID, Comment = V1)]
```

To get:

```
 User ID                                          Comment
1:     111 Comment 111,Second Comment 111,Third Comment 111
2:     222 Comment 222,Second Comment 222,Third Comment 222
3:     333                                      Comment 333
4:     444                                      Comment 444
5:     555                                      Comment 555
```

You can change the value for `collapse` if you'd like to separate the comments by a space `" "`, or some other symbol.